# "end if"/"else if" in AppleScript not working?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to code an AppleScript with a dialog box that has multiple buttons, which each execute different commands. My problem is that AppleScript Editor detects either "end if" or "else if" as a syntax error, as per the title.

For example:

```
set dialog to display dialog "Test" buttons {"1","2"}
set pressed to button returned of dialog
if pressed is equal to "1" then activate "Safari"
else if pressed is equal to "2" then beep
end if
```

AppleScript Editor displays the error "**Syntax Error**: Expected end of line, etc. but found “else if”."

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AppleScript's conditionals have two formats, a simple single-line format:

```
if condition then statement
```

and a multiline format:

```
if condition then
    statement
end if
```

If you want to use multiple statements or have multiple conditions (`else if`), you *must* use the multiline format:

```
set dialog to display dialog "Test" buttons {"1", "2"}
set pressed to button returned of dialog
if pressed is equal to "1" then
    activate "Safari"
else if pressed is equal to "2" then
    beep
end if
```

Comment: Can you put an end if on an else block?

Comment: @fungusanthrax You *must* end an `else` block with an `end if`. `else` is only available in the multiline format, and that always ends with `end if`. (Note that you can have as many `else if`s as you want, though.)

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!